# How find the largest integer $m$

Tags: sequences-and-series

A sequence $a_{1},a_{2},a_{3},\cdots, $ is defined by
$$a_{n}=2a_{n}a_{n+1}+3a_{n+1}$$
for all $n=1,2,3,\cdots,$ if $b_{n}=1+\dfrac{1}{a_{n}}$ for all $n=1,2,\cdots$ find the largest integer $m$ such that
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{n+\log_{3}{b_{k}}}>\dfrac{m}{24}$$
for all positive integer $n\ge 2$

my idea:we have
$$\dfrac{1}{a_{n+1}}+1=3(1+\dfrac{1}{a_{n}})$$
so $$b_{n+1}=3b_{n}$$
then we have
$$ b_{n}=b_{1}\cdot 3^{n-1}$$
let $\log_{3}(1+\dfrac{1}{a_{1}})=c$

then we 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{n+\log_{3}{b_{k}}}=\dfrac{1}{n+c}+\dfrac{1}{n+1+c}+\dfrac{1}{n+2+c}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{2n-1+c}$$

so
$$m<24\left(\dfrac{1}{n+c}+\dfrac{1}{n+1+c}+\dfrac{1}{n+2+c}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{2n-1+c}\right)_{min}$$
so I think 
$$24\left(\dfrac{1}{n+c}+\dfrac{1}{n+1+c}+\dfrac{1}{n+2+c}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{2n-1+c}\right)_{min}
=24\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\dfrac{1}{n+c}+\dfrac{1}{n+1+c}+\dfrac{1}{n+2+c}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{2n-1+c}\right)=24\ln{2}=16.635$$
so $m=16$?

but this problem answer $m=13$

meaning is my wrong? Thank you

Comment: you haven't given a starting value $a_1$. Was this intentional?

Comment: Thank you,@john This problem isn't given the starting value $a_{1}$

Answer (score 1):

You've done all the hard work to show that
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{n+\log_3b_k} =\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{n+k+c}.$$
If this is $>\frac m{24}$ for all $n\ge 2$, then especially
$$\frac1{3+c}+\frac1{4+c}>\frac m{24}.$$
For the claimed answer $m=13$ to be correct, a quick function plot shows that this requires that $c\in (-4,-3.5665\ldots)\cup(-3, 0.25881\ldots)$, i.e. $a_1\in(-\infty,-1.0384\ldots)\cup(-1.02027\ldots,-1.0125)\cup(3.0406\ldots,\infty)$.
So unless you are given more information about $a_1$, we cannot even verify if $m=13$ is a good answer or not.
At least you see from this that

- Not only the limit decides about the minimum
- The precise answer depends on $a_1$